# Create a live dashboard from data pulled via API using Grafana without a database

Tags: python, api, grafana, dashboard

I am currently getting a lot of data via API and I would like to display it on a dynamic dashboard.

So far, I saw that I could use Grafana, but it seems to require a database such as InfluxDB.

Is it possible to use Grafana without storing the data I get via API into a database, and then display only the data I get each with each request?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a RESTful API endpoint as a datasource using [SimpleJson datasource plugin](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-simple-json-datasource). In this way, you are able to remove the direct dependency to a database. However, your back-end needs to implement certain URLs and conforms to the plugin's request/response formats. I would recommend that you have a look at [this link](https://community.grafana.com/t/grafana-simplejson-dashboard/5627/4?u=mefraimsson) for a sample implementation, and see if it really meets your specific requirement.